# Manage dependencies of jar-files in jBoss 7.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss7.x, ear

I'm beginning with jboss and already have a trouble.

My project has next structure:

```
root pom.xml
 - core module
 - ddbac module
 - web module - includes core.jar and ddbac.jar
 -ear module - includes web.war
```

Each module also contains a pom.xml. All dependencies are declared in the root pom.xml.
When i execute `mvn clean install` inside of ear module, i'm getting ear-file, that contains web.war. This web.war contains core.jar and ddbac.jar.

After that i'm deploying this ear file into jBoss 7.1.1 - it works. But when i'm starting to test it - do some actions - i'm getting exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeansException from [Module "org.apache.cxf:main" from local module loader @5a0deddc (roots: /home/roman/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 99 more
```

So the question: how need to define dependencies correctly, that code from ddbac module could "see" libs in web.war?

Comment: Are you using spring? When CXF detects Spring in your application .... maybe id decides to use CXF+Spring implementation instead of CXF alone. https://community.jboss.org/thread/194685

Comment: yes, i'm using Spring, but problem was solved already (see an accepted answer). Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use descriptors to specify your dependencies. One of the following ways could be useful for you.

***application.xml***. Specify you library as module inside your application. Put application.xml into *ear-root/META-INF/*  and describe your project. You must specify something like that:

```
<application>
    <module>
        <web>
             <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
             <context-root>web</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>   
    <module>
        <java>web/WEB-INF/lib/ddbac.jar</java>
    </module>
</application>
```

OR

***jboss-app.xml***. It's JBOSS-specific configuration file, which is also should be located in *META-INF/*.

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 5.0//EN"
  "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd" >
<jboss-app>
    <library-directory>web/WEB-INF/lib</library-directory>
</jboss-app>
```

Comment: Yes, solution: add core and ddbac modules as modules in ear file: in ear pom.xml and in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, so they can use shared libraries.